# React FlatList image element won't grow to the flatlist view size, even with flexgrowth

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I've seen that this is a problem really debated, but every solution didn't gave me an effective answer, i've already setted flexGrowth but it only affect in the opposite way when i set that to a fractional number(not that of a clue i know). Anyway the only thing that affects the item height is the image style:

```
image: {
    flex:1,
    flexGrow: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    width: undefined,
    height: '100%',
    aspectRatio: 1,

    },
```

but i have a flatlist div that should bound that, even the item elements are generated in a container with flex:1, the image is also used as just ImageBackground in the container, i'm losing my mind over it...

Comment: I don't get the problem. You want to insert an image as an element on a FlatList and you want that image to stretch out in order to fill the FlatList? If this is the case, I have bad news. Let's speak very simple. You have a container (FlatList) that virtually has no height (theoretically, infinite elements = infinite height = infinite scroll, it's not "like this" but let me keep it simple). If you want your image to stretch to "infinity" it's obvious that it cannot be made and it doesn't work.

Comment: i don't want my images to be stretch to infinite, i want it to fit in the container, and i've also tried resizeMode and objectFit, but it has it's own dimension, not the proportional one of the div, it all should be flexible with handling with those 2 attribute i mentioned before...

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the width and the height of the flatlist container, then you can set the image dimensions to them:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  useWindowDimensions,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const images = Array(10).fill(null);
const randomImageUrl =
  'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.iSu2RcCcdm78xbxNDJMJSgHaEo%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=24cba8f41c7a91b13c2bee1c9f874592738582d63527ce43bf3440b4a7a544ff&ipo=images';

const Item = (props) => {
  const { width, height } = props;
  return (
    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <Text>
        Width:{width} Height:{height}
      </Text>
      <Image
        source={{
          uri: randomImageUrl,
        }}
        style={[styles.image, { width, height }]}
        // uncomment this to break aspectRatio
        // resizeMode="stretch"
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [flatlistLayout, setFlatlistLayout] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  });
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();

  // on the web the flatListLayout.height is the total height of the scroller
  const containerHeight =
    Platform.OS == 'web'
      ? // this calculates height assuming that there is nothing below the flatlist
        height - flatlistLayout.y
      : flatlistLayout.height;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Images</Text>
      <Text>
        Flatlist layout width:{flatlistLayout.width} height:
        {flatlistLayout.height}
      </Text>
      <View
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => setFlatlistLayout(nativeEvent.layout)}>
        <FlatList
          data={images}
          renderItem={(props) => (
            <Item {...props} width={width} height={containerHeight} />
          )}
          snapToInterval={containerHeight}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    // flex: 1,
    // flexGrow: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    // aspectRatio: 1,
  },
  itemContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 5,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/TZlyaj3qz)

Answer (score 0):

If you set width and height to undefined,remove all the flex from your styling, and add `resizeMode="contain"` the image will automatically scale to fit into the dimensions:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const images = Array(10).fill(null);
const randomImageUrl =
  'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.iSu2RcCcdm78xbxNDJMJSgHaEo%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=24cba8f41c7a91b13c2bee1c9f874592738582d63527ce43bf3440b4a7a544ff&ipo=images';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Images</Text>

      <FlatList
        data={images}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          console.log(item);
          return (
              <Image
                source={{
                  uri: randomImageUrl,
                }}
                style={styles.image}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    // flex: 1,
    // flexGrow: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    aspectRatio: 1,
  },
  itemContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 5,
  },
});
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/Jv6m7kNq0)

Comment: i tried demo on expo,  i noticed that you use <Image> as an outer container for the items, i used a safeareview with flex:1 and have kinda same result. My real aim is to generate the single images/coposition all screened(flex:1), not just following image rateo. I don't care if the image's gonna be stretched, that's another problem in the handling.

Comment: So you want the image to take up all the available space?